# What's wrong with this google map, api 3 implementation issue

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I have written something similar to this in the past using an older version of the google maps api I want to add some geocoding with some autocomplete using the api3. But my map won't even load in. The map will load in only if I take the map options and the geocoder off. Why is this?

```
    function mapLoad(){
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('#map').animate({height:300,width:300,opacity:1},1500);
    });

  var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(57.698254, 12.037024),
        zoom: 16,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
        panControl: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        scaleControl: true,
        streetViewControl: true,
        overviewMapControl: true
    };

    // Define map
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),mapOptions);

    // Define Gecoder
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  window.alert("no errors with map load");
}
```

EDITED neither the geocoder or the options work
i used [this](http://tech.cibul.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/geocode/index.html?PHPSESSID=gthpeblmaoouot4b17jsrp69t2) as a reference purely because it looks simple.

Answer (score 2):

Where are you calling mapLoad?  I assume in body onload.  I setup this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/aDEsOSuL/1/edit?html,js,console,output) without issue.  Does it help?

Comment: there thats perfect, i did notice one major difference. I have linked: //maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=3.x&amp;key=AIzaSyBp9PQhSJxHiJcRm6wETHbZr-eXcICanvI  where as you have http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false  That may be the problem, I feel a bit stupid now.

Comment: Paul, it looks like you were calling up a v2 version of the API. Check this out.  https://developers.google.com/maps/signup  Google maps v3 doesn't require a key; but if you have one, you're better able to monitor requests and such.

Comment: Also, this answered your question, please remember to mark it as such.